# How To Unit Test Entry Point Node.js File With Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have an entry point in my app that is executed via `npm start`. I'd like to run some tests on this script with Jest, but cannot figure out how I should do it. The script automatically runs, so if I import it into a Jest file, I can't call it individually in my `test` blocks like:

```
const entryPoint = require('./entry-point')

test('something', () => {
  entryPoint()
})
```

The code will already execute before it reaches any of the test blocks.

The code for the entry point is here:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const summarizeData = require("./summarize-data");

try {
  const fileName = process.argv[2];

  if (!fileName) {
    throw Error("Please enter a file name. ex: npm start <filename>");
  }

  if (!fs.existsSync(`${fileName}.json`)) {
    throw Error(`The file ${fileName}.json could not be found.`);
  }

  const jsonParsed = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${fileName}.json`, "utf8"));
  const data = summarizeData(jsonParsed);
  console.log(data);
} catch (error) {
  throw Error(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be enough to unit test `summarizeData` function.

Something like this (using [shouldJS](https://shouldjs.github.io/) for assertions):

```js
const should = require('should');

const fileName = 'testData';

test('it summarize data properly', () => {
  const jsonParsed = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${fileName}.json`, "utf8"));
  const dataSummarized = summarizeData(jsonParsed);
  dataSummarazied.something.should.be.equal(1); // TODO - add other assertions to cover all result
})
```